Can I remove the local file of a synced project in QField?
I am using QField Android to sync my data on the QGIS desktop. I would like to delete some of the projects which I downloaded from QFieldCloud (since some layers failed to upload to the cloud and caused some issues). I cannot find the options to remove the local file of the project within the app. Then I tried to access the project file and delete it. However, I cannot find the path to the local folder "/data/user/0/ch.opengis... " via file manager. After googling it, I realised that such path can be only seen after the device has been rooted.
I can actually uninstall my QField app and reinstall it to fulfil my propose. But I am wondering if I could remove a synced project in the QField app. Or is it possible to access the local file of the QField if my device has not been rooted?

In your app, view your list of QFieldCloud projects. Press and hold the project you want to delete and you should see a menu appear with the option to 'Remove stored project'.

Thanks a lot! This solves my problem!
